# Possible to disable touch simulation for slides but not scrollbar (idangerous swiper)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have an idangerous swiper on my page which successfully simulates touch events on both the slides and accompanying scrollbar (allowing a mouse click and movement to slide slides left or right).

This is fine, but I've now called draggable on the slides within the swiper, which means I need to stop this touch simulation (dragging the slides and moving them at the same time is causing confusion) - but only on the slides, not the scrollbar (I still need the scrollbar to function as it did subsequent to a mouse click and movement).

**What I've Tried**

According to the API I can disable touch simulation:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    simulateTouch: false,
    scrollbar: {
        container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: false,
        draggable: true,
        snapOnRelease: true
    }
});
```

This works as expected, but on both the scrollbar and slides, which is no good.

I've also tried returning false from a number of the events the swiper api exposes:

`var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  onTouchStart: function()
  {
      return false;
   },
   scrollbar: {
   container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
   hide: false,
   draggable: true,
   snapOnRelease: true
   }
});`

This doesn't have any effect at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is solution for Swiper-3.3.1

```
simulateTouch:false
```

Comment: This option is not documented yet. Thanks! I'm using this to disable swipe based navigation on non-touch devices.

Comment: Giving you an upvote and the answer vote. I believe mine was right at the time, a couple of years on and I think yours is more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that, for now, I'm happy with.

In the idangerous swiper source (idangerous.swiper-2.1.js) I return false from the `onTouchStart` function (line 1120) so my code now resembles the following:

```
    function onTouchStart(event) {
    if (params.preventLinks) _this.allowLinks = true;
    //Exit if slider is already was touched

    return false;

    if (_this.isTouched || params.onlyExternal) {
        return false;
    }
```

This is non-invasive to the way the scrollbar prototype works too, so the scrollbar's touch events are left in-tact.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Swiper-6.6.2.

Just add to class of the object you do not want to be swiped 'swiper-no-swiping'.
Then just add below code to your js file.

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping'
});
```