# allowTouchMove property of Swiper.js is not working in framework7

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7, swiper.js

I am building Cordova based hybrid app using [Framework7](http://framework7.io/) and it has in-built support of [Swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper). I need a swiper in my app and for that I have created one with following settings:

```
        //Create Instance of Swiper
        var awesomeSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            speed: 200,
            spaceBetween: 100
        });
```

And it's working well but I need swiper that only can be controlled by custom control buttons for that I changed previous code as below

```
        //Create Instance of Swiper
        var intraBAISwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            speed: 200,
            spaceBetween: 100,
            allowTouchMove: false
        });
```

Setting property 'allowTouchMove' to false, didn't make any different in swiper. I still can change slides using Sliding Gesture...Why?? :-(

Do you have any idea?? Please Help me..

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Similar post found, this could be helpful !! :) <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780805/possible-to-disable-touch-simulation-for-slides-but-not-scrollbar-idangerous-sw

Comment: Thanks @RaghuMothuk